# Thinking Sphinx indexing performance

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a large index definition that takes too long to index. I suspect the main problem is caused by the many LEFT OUTER JOINs generated.

I saw [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/thinking-sphinx/CBdWy-RivaU/tBRlLci83IkJ), but can't find documentation about using `source: :query`, which seems to be part of the solution.

My index definition and the resulting query can be found here: https://gist.github.com/jonsgold/fdd7660bf8bc98897612

How can I optimize the generated query to run faster during indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that worked best (from the [linked question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/thinking-sphinx/CBdWy-RivaU/tBRlLci83IkJ)). Basically, you can remove a piece of the main query `sql_query` and define it separately as a `sql_joined_field` in the `sphinx.conf` file.

It's important to add all relevant sql conditions to each `sql_joined_field` (such as sharding indexes by modulo on the ID). Here's the new definition:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define(
  :incident,
  with: :active_record,
  delta?: false,
  delta_processor: ThinkingSphinx::Deltas.processor_for(ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::ResqueDelta)
) do
    indexes "SELECT incidents.id * 51 + 7 AS id, sites.name AS site FROM incidents LEFT OUTER JOIN sites ON sites.id = site_id WHERE incidents.deleted = 0 AND EXISTS (SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE accounts.status = 'enabled' AND incidents.account_id = id) ORDER BY id", as: :site, source: :query
    ...
    has
    ...
end

ThinkingSphinx::Index.define(
  :incident,
  with: :active_record,
  delta?: true,
  delta_processor: ThinkingSphinx::Deltas.processor_for(ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::ResqueDelta)
) do
    indexes "SELECT incidents.id * 51 + 7 AS id, sites.name AS site FROM incidents LEFT OUTER JOIN sites ON sites.id = site_id WHERE incidents.deleted = 0 AND incidents.delta = 1 AND EXISTS (SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE accounts.status = 'enabled' AND incidents.account_id = id) ORDER BY id", as: :site, source: :query
    ...
    has
    ...
end
```

The magic that defines the field `site` as a separate query is the option `source: :query` at the end of the line.

Notice the core index definition has the parameter `delta?: false`, while the delta index definition has the parameter `delta?: true`. That's so I could use the condition `WHERE incidents.delta = 1` in the delta index and filter out irrelevant records.

I found sharding didn't perform any better, so I reverted to one unified index.

See the whole index definition here: https://gist.github.com/jonsgold/05e2aea640320ee9d8b2.

**Important to remember!**

The Sphinx document ID offset must be handled manually. That is, whenever an index for another model is added or removed, my calculated document ID will change. This must be updated.

So, in my example, if I added an index for a different model (not `:incident`), I would have to run `rake ts:configure` to find out my new offset and change `incidents.id * 51 + 7` accordingly.

Comment: I'm so late to the party! Thank you for the gist. One thing I found out is that you have access to `@index` inside the define block and you can do `@index.delta?` in your conditions to avoid splitting the indexes in two.

Answer (score 2):

The 'standard' sphinx solution to this would be to use ranged queries.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ex-ranged-queries

... splitting up the query into lots of small parts, so the database server has a better chance of being able to run the query (rather than one huge query)

But I have no idea how to actully enable that in Thinking Sphinx. Can't see anything in the documentation. Could help you edit the sphinx.conf, but also not sure how TS will cope with you manually editing the config file.

Comment: It seems that joined fields would better address my problem of indexing performance: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-joined-field. Any idea how to implement this in TS?

Comment: Looking closer at the gist notice now has ranged query already, did you edit the gist? If not sorry didn't notice that. Joined fields are also useful, sorry don't know if TS can enable their use.

Comment: No, I didn't. I think that comes standard with TS. Your advice is still valuable, however. If I understand correctly, ranged queries can improve search-time performance. I want to improve indexing-time performance.

Comment: It is very easy to enable this in Thinking Sphinx for example 

```
 indexes "SELECT incidents.id * 51 + 7 AS id , sites.name AS site FROM incidents WHERE (incidents.id BETWEEN $start AND $end); SELECT IFNULL(MIN(`incidents`.`id`), 1), IFNULL(MAX(`incidents`.`id`), 1) FROM `incidents`" , as: :site, source: ranged_query
````